# CQWP display custom field from all lists in subsite

Tags: content-query-web-part, custom-field-types

I am trying to build a CQWP to display custom fields on list items from several lists in a subsite. So far i have configured the CQWP.webpart file to display the custom field when i query by "Show items from the following list:" following [this tutorial](http://msftplayground.com/2011/01/sharepoint-content-query-web-part-like-a-sharepoint-list-view/). But when i choose "Show items from the following site and all subsites:" the custom columns disappear.

In the "ItemStyle.xsl" file i defined my own template, and am including the following code to display all available columns:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
    P:<xsl:value-of select="name()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

My custom fields disappear when i search the whole site. How can I add my custom field to the site's default field list so i can display it?